# How do I find the total combination of possibilities of going to $119$ different stops from $3$ starting stops in a station?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I understand that I can find resources for combination and permutations online, but as it stands I cannot fit what I learnt online with my situation. My situation may not be unique but to me as of now it is very difficult to understand which type of permutation or combination to use, so I thought to ask here. Not asking for someone to help calculation a simple permutation (or combination), but explain how to go from my problem to deciding which one to use and then using it to find the answer.

As the topic states, my problem is that I need to find out of a possible 119 train station stops, how many different ways I can go from $3$ *specific* stops to all *other* stops.

How do I go from knowing this above to deciding to use combination or permutations, and then which type of combination or permutation thereafter. It's easier when using lottery, picking colored balls etc, but when put into a real scenario like this one its hard for me to tell if this is ordered, unordered, etc.

In any case I hope someone can shed some light to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This information may not be enough, I need to know how the stations are interconnected to form an answer.

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa Well they cross over each other quite a lot, but if you think of it simpler think of 3 lines, each line being a train line, each with 10 stops, and they cross each other at a certain point (where you can transfer from one train to the other). How would you go about finding the combination of these 30 stops in this example, if you only could start from the first three stops of one of the three lines? Even an approach to a simpler version can give me an idea how to approach mine with 119 stops

Comment: I am unsure that I understand correctly. In the scenario you described in the comment there is one way to each stop (I am assuming that the lines doesn't cross only at the transition point) so you have 29 ways to reach the 29 stations from a certain prechosen station. But in this frame of reference the question is not hard that is why I believe that I am misinterpreting something

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa how did you get 29? It may not be difficult for you but for me it's quite a challenge because I never learned this, and my issue is not the calculation its the approach itself, i need some help deciding to use permutation or combination and which type of perm / comb to use in my scenario. Like which factors made you to decide to use what. I want to know the deciding points so I can learn how to make the same approach in another scenario. It's easier for me when I read about picking colored balls or looking at locks combinations, but then Im confused in this real world scenario

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa please look up taipei mrt map to have an idea of the train lines, that's what im working on right now. But i have 3 pre-known stations Im starting off from, to reach all other stations. How many possible routes are there to take? 29 sounds impossible

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the situation with $10$ stations in each line. Say you have line $1,2$ and $3$ and let us call the stations $A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1,E_1,F_1,G_1,H_1,J_1,K_1$, $A_2,B_2,C_2,D_2,E_2,F_2,G_2,H_2,J_2,K_2$ and $A_3,B_3,C_3,D_3,E_3,F_3,G_3,H_3,J_3,K_3$ respectively. Let us also assume that the station where you can change is $E_1,E_2$ and $E_3$, since this is a station that is shared by all lines it is not smart to give it three names let us call it $O$ instead (in the comments I considered them different that is how I got the number $29$).

So, say you would like to travel from $B_1$. You have $9$ different routes to reach all stations in line $1$ ($10$ if you consider "staying at $B_1$" as an "empty" route, in the comments I didnt count with this). Also we do not allow traveling back and forth like $B_1\to C_1\to D_1\to C_1\to D_1\to O$ since this makes that the problem has infinite solutions.

Let us say that we dont consider empty routes so we can reach all stations in line $1$ in $9$ ways.

Taking into account line number $2$ from $B_1$ you have to travel to $O$ and from here you have $9$ different routes, one to each of $A_2, B_2,\ldots J_2,K_2$ this is $9$ different routes.

Same goes if you would like to change to line $3$.

This means that from $B_1$ there are $9+9+9=27$ different routes you could take.

Observe that the same is true if you start from $O$, the transit station.

So if you pick $3$ starting stations you would have $27$ possible routes from each of them.

Why I was puzzled as you can see in the comments is because there is not much combinatorics included in the solution so I thought I am misunderstanding the question.

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How would I go about this with taipei mrt station then? can you have a look at the map? last i checked its 119 stations, and assume we want our ending /starting point to be at fixed to 3 specific stations (any station). How would we calculate it then?

Comment: Why is this problem relevant? Do you wanna make a program calculating the shortest route? Or some probability question? The thing is that MRT in Taipei has a really complicated layout with many loops and transit stations. So many many alternate routes are possible.

Comment: because that is my original question, given that there are 3 possible starting fixed points (stations), what are the number of total ways I can go to 119 stations? Even if its complicated I thought it would be simpler for someone who understand combinations to come up with the maximum number, disregarding loops. Just simply how many ways are there to go to 119 stations from 3 stations, and I hope to know how you came up with the answer and the thought process if possible. My main trouble is HOW people get from a problem to deciding what to use to check the total combinations.